# Elementref does not exist on type HeaderComponent?

Tags: angular

code the prog to detect the mouse click inside the component or outside the component.but it show the err 
'elementref' does not exist on type 'Headercomponent'

```
import { OnInit, Input, Output, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
  },
  templateUrl: '...........',
  providers: ............,
  styleUrls: ............,
})

export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(myElement: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = myElement;
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    var clickedComponent = event.target;
    var inside = false;
    do {
      if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
        inside = true;
      }
      clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
    } while (clickedComponent);
    if (inside) {
      console.log('inside');

    } else {
      console.log('outside');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, yes: you haven't declared a property named elementRef. This is TypeScript, not JavaScript. Properties must be declared. The most concise way to do that is `constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. Why are you still using var, BTW? Use const, or let when necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For using ElementRef, you need to have a reference for that element in your HTML. So for the element you are taking the reference, declare a local variable on it and use ViewChild directive.

**TS file**

```
import { OnInit, Input, Output, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
  },
  templateUrl: '...........',
  providers: ............,
  styleUrls: ............,
})

export class HeaderComponent {

  @ViewChild('myElement', { read: ElementRef }) myElement: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    var clickedComponent = event.target;
    var inside = false;
    do {
      if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
        inside = true;
      }
      clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
    } while (clickedComponent);
    if (inside) {
      console.log('inside');

    } else {
      console.log('outside');
    }
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<div #myElement>Demo text</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the error, and the code you post does something completely different from what the OP does (and wants to do).

Comment: I have explained it in my answer description. One cannot initialize an elementRef in constructor without the reference of any HTML element if you want to use the nativeElement property of ElementRef.

Comment: Yes, one can. It simply injects the ElementRef of the component's host element. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zrykh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Notice the code, here OP is talking about the click event on a particular element, that whether the click is outside or inside. So the code is according to the requirement.

Comment: No. Not at all. It says, I quote: "detect the mouse click inside the component or outside the component". Not inside an element of the template of the component. The goal is to inject the host element of the component. Just read the question.

Comment: event.target never returns a component instance. It's just a plain HTML. Let OP decide what he wants. Why be you judging and downvoting? If you have some view, post the answer and let the decision be on OP.

Comment: The OP has decided. You just decided to do something else because you didn't understand the OP's code, nor the OP's question. I'm downvoting because this answer doesn't explain the compilation error that the OP got, and provide a "fix" that does something completely different than what is required.

Comment: Where did he mention?

Comment: I am beginner on angular but, Mr JB Nizet  your answer help me to remove the err from my code but prachi's answer help me to solve my issue so i give both positive vote